# Can i use EDB postgres failover manager without having a witness node >

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, edb, automatic-failover

I am having one master node and one standby node with EDB streaming replication enabled. I want to use EDB failover manager tool. However i dont have any witness node. Is there any way i can use my standby node as witness node or how it will work , if i do the failover manager setup without the witness node.?